# How can I merge lists with ansible 2.6.3

Tags: ansible

In the past I used ansible 2.3.1.0 and now want to use ansible 2.6.3.

I now want to install some packages with apt. therefore I have to source lists and I want to merge them in one. In ansible 2.3.1.0 I just used the following:

```
apt_packages:
- "{{ packages_list1 + packages_list2 }}"
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k0tmag/ansible_module_apt.py\", line 1128, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k0tmag/ansible_module_apt.py\", line 1106, in main\r\n
   allow_unauthenticated=allow_unauthenticated\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k0tmag/ansible_module_apt.py\", line 521, in install\r\n    pkgspec = expand_pkgspec_from_fnmatches(m, pkgspec, cache)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k0tmag/ansible_module_apt.py\", line 439, in expand_pkgspec_from_fnmatches\r\n
pkgname_pattern, version = package_split(pkgspec_pattern)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k0tmag/ansible_module_apt.py\", line 312, in package_split\r\n
parts = pkgspec.split('=', 1)\r\nAttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

Content of the role:

````
  apt:
    state: present
    name: "{{ apt_packages }}"
    force: yes
  when: apt_packages is defined```
````

Comment: can you share more info i.e debug logs and more content of the playbook

Comment: Hello the playbook is nothing speceal just an apt install but i will edit it to the original post

Comment: I also edited a longer output of the error code

Answer (score 1):

With `apt_packages: "{{ packages_list1 + packages_list2 }}"`(without the `-`), it will work.

Working sample:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    pkgs1: 
      - perl
      - python
    pkgs2:
      - vim
      - tar
    packages: "{{ pkgs1 + pkgs2 }}"

  tasks:
    -  apt:
         name: "{{ packages }}"
         state: present
```